# Node JS Synchronous Reading of One Line Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this following case, where i have `data.txt`, contains thousands of lines.

My goal is to read each line of those file and pickup some data and store it in an array. I use `readline` and `fs.createReadStream`.

Here is what i did:

```
const readingText = async () => {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(
    "./data.txt"
  );

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  let dd = [];
  rl.on("line", line => {
    dd.push(line.split(":")[1]);
  });
  rl.on("close", async line => {
    console.log(dd);
    return dd;
  });
};

const someFunc = async () => {
  try {
    const ff = await readingText();
    console.log(ff);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
};

someFunc();
```

The problem is `console.log(ff)` will always return `undefined` while `console.log(dd)` is correctly return desired `dd` array, why is that? and how to make `console.log(ff)` wait till `ff` variable get assigned to the value of `dd` array?

Thanks

Comment: event based execution won't tell your async function to wait and terminate as per the return statement. You might want to wrap it in a promise and then use someFunc with await.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: adding as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event based execution doesn't wait parent async function.

Try this:

```
const readingText = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(
      "./data.txt"
    );

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    let dd = [];
    rl.on("line", line => {
      dd.push(line.split(":")[1]);
    });
    rl.on("close", line => {
      console.log(dd);
      return resolve(dd);
    });
  });

};

const someFunc = async () => {
  try {
    const ff = await readingText();
    console.log(ff);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
};

someFunc();
```

Comment: Also I skipped the reject part. If rl.on('error'), you might want to reject the promise so that you get correct try/catch flow.

Comment: yes, thanks wrapping inside promise is great tips i just realize.